# MySQL case sensitive charset

Tags: mysql

I have this question: is there a case sensitive charset I can insert as default for mySQL tables? Because I would like the attribute username in table user to be case sensitive. I've tried with some case sensitive charset (such as latin1_general_cs), but the database seems not to find that charset, so now it is set to utf8mb4 (but if I modify manually the charset after the insertion of the table, I can choose between many charsets, some of them case sensitive). But I would like to set a case sensitive charset as default, otherwise I would have some problems when I create foreign keys on the attribute username (such as in table cart).

```sql
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `users`;
    CREATE TABLE `users`(
      `username` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'user',
      `password` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000',
      `email` varchar(30) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'email',
      `residenza` varchar(50) DEFAULT 'sconosciuto',
      PRIMARY KEY(`username`)
    )ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8_bin; 

    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `cart`;
    CREATE TABLE `cart`(
      `username` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'user',
      `titolo` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'sconosciuto',
      `numero` int NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
      PRIMARY KEY(`username`, `titolo`),
      FOREIGN KEY(`username`) REFERENCES `users`(`username`),
      FOREIGN KEY(`titolo`) REFERENCES `cd`(`titolo`)
    )ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

Comment: Try add `COLLATE utf8_bin` to table definition. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-table.html

Comment: *but the database seems not to find that charset* `select * from information_schema.collations;`

Comment: @Dmitry I've updated my question with your suggestion, but the database shows me this error: _COLLATION 'utf8_bin' is not valid for CHARACTER SET 'utf8mb4'_

Comment: @Akina with that query the database shows me for example latin1_general_cs but if I insert that as default I get this error: _Unknown character set: 'latin1_general_cs'_

Comment: *the database shows me for example `latin1_general_cs` but if I insert that as default I get this error: `Unknown character set: 'latin1_geenral_cs'`* I see a typo. And always check that the collation matches the charset.

Comment: Ok, I didn't notice that you're using mb4 type. Then try `COLLATE utf8mb4_bin`

Comment: Thanks to everybody, I solved!